# How does KIE Server load or be loaded from the beginning?

Tags: java, jboss

just as what I mentioned in title.

I'm using KIE 6.5.4.Final. An official KIE Workbench distribution running in a `apache-tomcat-7.0.70` acts as my KIE Controller. And I'm running my KIE Server instance in docker container from image `jboss.com/jboss/kie-server-showcase`.

I'm new to KIE system and I found it's hard to catch the real clue about how KIE Server works (I need run jBPM project there).

I'll be appreciate if any suggestion, thank you very much.

Actually, I have started my KIE Workbench according to its README. However, I have no idea about how to create the data source for a KIE Server manually. At the end, I just specified following environments for KIE Server docker container and make the KIE Server to register to KIE Workbench.

```
KIE_SERVER_ID
KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP_ADDR
KIE_WB_PORT_8080_TCP
KIE_WB_ENV_KIE_CONTEXT_PATH
DOCKER_IP
DOCKER_PORT
```

In my solution, there are several KIE Servers registered to KIE Controller (A KIE Workbench for simplicity). These KIE Servers only run Rules and Processes without any extra business logical. However, I do not know any remote listener such as ProcessEventListener can work in remote KIE Client, which retrieved by `KieServicesClient#getServicesClient()`. Is there any mechanism to achieve this?

Finally, my idea is adding a new `ProcessEventListener` on KIE Server and it will post a new message every time a task will be triggered.

So, the real problem should be how KIE Server is being loaded from the beginning. Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the best answer but a choice.

After I've asked the question on IRQ group, I found the class `org.kie.server.services.Bootstrap`. It's should be the entrance.

Actually, a KIE server act as an web application running in tomcat or jboss(or other supported container listed here: http://www.drools.org/download/download.html). Which means there should be one or more web listeners that will initialize the KIE server itself. In other words, all classes annotated with annotation `@WebListener` should be paid special attention.

---

But how does the container know these classes annotated need to be loaded? The key factor is the listener defined at `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

I thought this might be help.